# adding items to listview from another activity

Tags: android, jquery, listview

I have my "Cart" listview that displays the items that were clicked from the main activity. I have also a listview in my mainactivity the displays all the items. Whenever I click "Buy", the item is successfully sent to the listview of the "Cart". then in my Cart activity, I have "ADD ITEMS" button that goes back to the MainActivity to add more items. If I click "Buy" once again, the item chosen is overwriting the existing item.

Am I missing something?

Here is my Cart.class

```
public class Cart extends MainActivity {

ListView cartList;
CartCustomAdapter cartCustomAdapter;
String name, price;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

    ArrayList<Order> cartArray = new ArrayList<Order>();

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    Button checkout =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_out);
    Button add_item = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_item);

    name = bundle.getString("i_name");
    price = bundle.getString("i_price");

    add_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Cart.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    cartArray.add(new Order(name,price,"1"));

    cartCustomAdapter = new CartCustomAdapter(Cart.this,R.layout.list_cart,cartArray);
    cartList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cart_list);
    cartList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    cartList.setAdapter(cartCustomAdapter);
    cartCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

}

Comment: Why are you subclassing the MainActivity?

Comment: I want my cart.class to have the same toolbar.

Comment: You could have used a single Activity and two fragments maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the cartArray static and an instance field, so it gets created once, even though you should use sqlite database instead to really persist such structured data. Remove the ArrayList cartArray = new ArrayList(); from your onCreate activity.

```
public class Cart extends MainActivity {

ListView cartList;
CartCustomAdapter cartCustomAdapter;
String name, price;
static ArrayList<Order> cartArray = new ArrayList<Order>();

}
```

Comment: it worked sir!. thank you. can you explain a little more about the purpose of the "static" in Instantiating an ArrayList.

Comment: i know then you should need some basics of Object oriented programming. A static variable is a kind of global variable, like in other procedural languages, meaning when you create objects of that class then all the objects will have reference to that variable or the variable will be shared among these objects.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList cartArray = new ArrayList();

You are creating new arraylist everytime you navigate to Cart Activity , thats why only one item gets added in the arraylist . You need to persist the old list and add the new item in the cart list so you need to do the following :

1. ArrayList cartArray = new ArrayList(); remove this line .
2. Save the items already added to cart somewhere so that you can fetch  and display them when needed . You can make singleton class or local DB according to your project requirement .

Comment: exactly what I said 0.o

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can update the arraylist:

Call the MainActivity using `startActivityForResult`. When you click buy on MainActivity, you send the selected items back to the Cart.
In the Cart activity you can receive the items by implementing the `onActivityResult` method and update the listview.

For more info: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Also note that its not a good practice to subclass Activity that is used to display another screen.